# Problems with encrypt/decrypt between Android and PHP

Tags: php, android, encryption

hello fellow programmers,

I followed a tutorial at http://www.androidsnippets.com/encrypt-decrypt-between-android-and-php to send a `String` encrypted by PHP back to my Android client where I want to decrypt it again. The encryption/decryption part is running like a charm on my PHP Server and I'm also able to deliver the encrypted String to my Android Client, but I can't figure out how to decrypt the String in Android... all I got are some cryptic (haha) signs...

problem description:
I'm sending the IV and Encryption Key I generated on the Android Client via REST Api to my PHP Server which is processing some database queries and encrypting a String with the given IV and Encrytpion Key which is then returned to the Android client.
The Client is able to read out the returned value and to get the encrypted String, BUT the encryption is not acting as awaited...

I followed the upper tutorial strictly but I can't figure out what the problem would be....

here's the code for encryption on PHP:

```
class MCrypt {
private $iv;
private $key;
private $mode;

function __construct() {
    $this->mode = 'cbc';
}

public function setIV($iv) {
    $this->iv = $iv;
}

public function setKey($key) {
    //$this->key = $this->hex2bin($key);
    $this->key = $key;
}

public function getIV() {
    return $this->iv;
}

public function getKey() {
    return $this->key;
}

public function encrypt($value) {
    $iv = $this->iv;
    $td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', '', $this->mode, $iv);

    mcrypt_generic_init($td, $this->key, $iv);

    $encrypted = mcrypt_generic($td, $value);

    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
    mcrypt_module_close($td);

    return bin2hex($encrypted);
}


public function decrypt($value) {
    $value = $this->hex2bin($value);
    $iv = $this->iv;

    $td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', '', $this->mode, $iv);

    mcrypt_generic_init($td, $this->key, $iv);
    $decrypted = mdecrypt_generic($td, $value);

    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
    mcrypt_module_close($td);

    return utf8_encode(trim($decrypted));
}


protected function hex2bin($hexdata) {
    $bindata = '';

    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($hexdata); $i += 2) {
        $bindata .= chr(hexdec(substr($hexdata, $i, 2)));
    }

    return $bindata;
}

}
```

and here's how I implemented it:

```
$value = "some data I want to read out";
// create new MCrypt object
$mcrypt = new MCrypt();
// set IV to hash
$mcrypt->setIV($data['iv']);
// set key to salt
$mcrypt->setKey($data['key']);
// encrypt the key
$enc = $mcrypt->encrypt($value);

return array("data"=>$enc);
```

So, this is returning the correctly encoded String (tested with the PHP decrypt function, which is decoding the String to the awaited result).

Here's what the JAVA implementation looks like:
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import android.util.Log;

public class MCrypt {
    private static final String TAG = MCrypt.class.getSimpleName();

```
private String iv;
private String key;
private IvParameterSpec mIvParameterSpec;
private SecretKeySpec mSecretKeySpec;
private Cipher mCipher;

public MCrypt(String iv, String key) {
    Log.v(TAG, "IV Bytes.length=" + iv.getBytes().length);
    this.iv = cut(iv, 16);
    Log.i(TAG, "IV = " + this.iv + ", Bytelength=" + this.iv.getBytes().length);
    this.key = key;

    mIvParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(this.iv.getBytes());
    mSecretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(this.key.getBytes(), "AES");

    try {
        mCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Got Exception while initializing mCipher: " + e.toString(), e);
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Got Exception while initializing mCipher: " + e.toString(), e);
    }
}

public String getIV() {
    return this.iv;
}

public byte[] decrypt(String code) throws Exception {
    if(code == null || code.length() == 0) {
        throw new Exception("Emtpy string given");
    }

    byte[] decrypted = null;

    try {
        mCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, mSecretKeySpec, mIvParameterSpec);
        decrypted = mCipher.doFinal(hexToBytes(code));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("[decrypt] " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return decrypted;
}

private byte[] hexToBytes(String str) {
    if (str==null) {
        return null;
    } else if (str.length() < 2) {
        return null;
    } else {
        int len = str.length() / 2;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
        for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
                buffer[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i*2,i*2+2),16);
        }
        return buffer;
    }
}

private String cut(String s, int n) {
    byte[] sBytes = s.getBytes();

    if(sBytes.length < n) {
        n = sBytes.length;
    }

    int n16 = 0;
    boolean extraLong = false;

    int i = 0;

    while(i < n) {
        n16 += (extraLong) ? 2 : 1;
        extraLong = false;

        if((sBytes[i] & 0x80) == 0) {
            i += 1;
        }
        else if((sBytes[i] & 0xC0) == 0x80) {
            i += 2;
        }
        else if((sBytes[i] & 0xE0) == 0xC0) {
            i += 3;
        } else {
            i += 4;
            extraLong = true;
        }
    }
    return s.substring(0, n16);
}
}
```

If I want now to en/decrypt a String (e.g. "Hello World") I get this String in return: af8d89fa962794d5b945b74c4b6fd9b6, which is decoded by the PHP implementation to "Hello World", but JAVA just gives some funny signs...

I know that this is a lot of code but I'd appreciate any help here on this issue!

Thanks in advance for your patience and time to read the thread ;)

---

So, what I've come up so far is that **these 'cryptic' signs I got instead of the expected decrypted output are actually the address of the byte array itself**, even if I try to create a new String from this byte array by using `String str = new String(byteArray);` I get an output which looks like `[B@44e8c0c8`... what's going on here? Any ideas??

Comment: Any reason you aren't just using SSL for the data transmission?

Comment: actually, I just want to make sure that the String I return is not submitted in clear text since it is a bit of sensual data ;)

Comment: SSL is not really an option as it's not requested by the customer also and it's stated that I should en/decrypt the String between Server and Client...

Comment: "it's stated that I should en/decrypt the String between Server and Client" — What?! That doesn't make sense. Are you trying to say "The client should encrypt messages to the server, and the server should decrypt messages from the client, and vice versa, but when the message is between the two, then a third party should not be able to intercept it and decrypt it"? Because that is what SSL does. If a client doesn't request SSL but does request that data is encrypted in transit, then use SSL. It solves the requested problem. They didn't tell you to avoid SSL (and if they did, they shouldn't).

Comment: no, they didn't tell me to avoid SSL but there is no budget left for any certificate (even if it is the cheapest thing on earth) as they won't give any extra money for anything. Also I'm stuck at this problem and I'd love to find out what went wrong prior to give up and start from the very beginning at another end...

Comment: Since it is an app and not a regular browser, I don't think there are any problems in using a self-signed cert … so the cost is "free". Even if we discard that option, then a quick google search found an (*not* self-signed) SSL cert provider for $10/year. Does that really compare unfavourably to the cost of your time?

Comment: no, it doesn't but I'm stuck on my problem and I'm trying to get a solution to this. Thanks for your time and help but I want to solve this particular problem first as it is the main part of a working package and therefore I'm not able to switch on SSL that easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a long research and (finally) a restart of my computer I found the solution for my problem which I want to share with you:

first, I changed my `hex2Bin(String str)` function to the following:

```
private byte[] hex2ByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                             + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}
```

after that, I still got the same error over and over again, Android would only show the address of the byte array instead of the decrypted String so I consulted Harry Potter and he told me the magic to be able to get this sorted out, and now I want to share this with you... the most important thing is.... RESTART YOUR COMPUTER if you're working with Eclipse/Motodev Studio more than a few hours a day - it will save you some time and money, for sure ;)

Comment: Hi, I wrote that code. If you have any other problem with the code, just let me know and I'll try to help

Comment: @SERPRO, I'm using your code in my project. But I want the IV to be randomly generated for each query and insert it in my db via PHP or Java. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: @input you can modify it but then you need to pass the generated IV from PHP to JAVA or de other way around, or else the encryption/decryption will not match. You can generate a random IV in PHP with http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this problem may be because when you call the `encrypt` method in PHP it is using one key for encrypting, but **when you decrypt the encrypted string in Java code, you have to generate keys which will be different from that of the PHP keys**, therefore you are getting these special characters in decrypted string

You can pass objects from PHP to Java code or use PHP-Java bridge